# Displaying an image on a PdfButtonFormField

Tags: itext7

I am using the following code:
    `btnfield.setImage(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());`
to add an image to a `PdfButtonFormField` object. The code worked fine, until I had to add the following line to my code:
    `PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(this.pdf, true).put(PdfName.NeedAppearances, new PdfBoolean(true));` 
Since then, the image doesn't appear - the appearance of the button is a gray background with the word "Button". 
I thought to use the `setAppearance()` method, but am at a loss as to how to do that, for lack of documentation. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you setting **NeedAppearances** to true? That flag tips off the viewer that an appearance is not set for widget annotations and for it to supply a default value. In your reader's case the default value is a grey button.

Comment: I didn't set it until I encountered a problem that a Hebrew default value in a textbox wasn't being displayed unless the textbox was clicked on.